# set() function works on 2017a but crash on 2018b

Tags: matlab

The following codes works on 2017a, but failed on 2018b
I use debugger step by step, and found out it crashes at **set(axs,'Parent',p);** 
on version 2018b.
version 2018b at line **set(axs,'Parent',p);** will call the program usejava.m, but not 2017a. Please help.

```
p=uipanel(gcf,'Units','normalized','Position',
  [0 0.2 10.8],'BorderType','none','Tag','CursorPanel1');        
set(p,'BackgroundColor',get(gcf,'Color'));
axs=findall(gcf,'Type','Axes');  
set(axs,'Parent',p);
```

Comment: How many handles do you get in `axs`?

Comment: The axs on console shows:
axs = 
3 X 1 graphics array:
Axes (Endurance Test I)
Axes
AxesToolbar